# Updated Chrome Browser not found in Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver NuGet package

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

The chrome browser upgraded to the version 89.0.4389.90.

But the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver nuget package is not available for the updated chrome version. How to upgrade selenium chrome web driver?

[image: Updated Chrome]

[image: Nuget Version]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Selenium driver version "89.0.4389.23" is working for me with the Chrome version 89.0.4389.90 (windows 10 64 bit).

Download link: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=89.0.4389.23/
Can you see if it works for you as well.
I did  faced an issue with chrome not starting with below error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
```

As a workaround I did:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.binary_location = "C:\...\chrome.exe"
b = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions, executable_path="<driver location>\chrome.exe")
```

After this I did not faced any crash issues.
Hope you find this helpful.

Note: The above code is in python but the approach should work for you.

Comment: Same versions not working on linux: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)